# flutter function _startMicrotaskLoop throw exception without clear trigger

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I have an app in flutter that has multiple screens with google maps on it, it throws an exception in the flutter framework function _startMicrotaskLoop

```
  _isInCallbackLoop = true;
  try {
    // Moved to separate function because try-finally prevents
    // good optimization.
    _microtaskLoop();
  } finally {
    _lastPriorityCallback = null;
    _isInCallbackLoop = false;
    if (_nextCallback != null) {
      _AsyncRun._scheduleImmediate(_startMicrotaskLoop);
    }
  }
}
```

there's no clear indication in the error messsage or in the app's behavior as to how this error gets triggered, has anyone else had the same issue, how did you solve it ?